# Python regex matching enumerated lists

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a python string of the following format

```
string = 'Some text.\n1. first item\n2. second item\n3. third item\nSome more text.'
```

What I want to match is the substring `\n1. first item\n2. second item\n3. third item`, effectively, the enumerated list within the string. For my purposes, I do *not* necessarily need to match the first `\n`.

What I've tried so far:

- `re.findall('\n.*\d\..*', req, re.DOTALL)`
- `re.findall('\n.*\d\..*?', req, re.DOTALL)`

The first case finds the last line of the text which I don't want, and the second case doesn't find the rest of line 3. The key difficulty I'm facing is that I don't know how to make the first `.*` greedy (and match over newlines) but make the second `.*` simply match up to a newline.

**Note:** The number of items in the enumerated string is unknown so I can't just match three numbered lines. It could be any number of lines. The string provided is simply an example which happens to have three enumerated items.

Comment: Does it have to match ALL items in the list in one big string or is matching each item and then adding each item to a collection acceptable?

Comment: @LewsTherin I suppose the latter is acceptable, I was just hoping a single regex command could handle this, specifically so I could match multiple, separate enumerated lists in a single string.

Answer (score 1):

How about using line-wise matching and a filter?

```
string = 'Some text.\n1. first item\n2. second item\n3. third item\nSome more text.'
is_enumerated = re.compile(r"^\d+\.\s")

matches = list(filter(lambda line: is_enumerated.match(line), string.splitlines()))
# ['1. first item', '2. second item', '3. third item']
```

You can join the matches with `\n`, if you want.

Comment: Why not just `re.findall('\d\..*', string)`?

Comment: Because I did not think of that, plain and simple. :) Your suggestion is better.